# I want to make the execution order of threads sequentially one after another

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, winapi

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int count = 0;

DWORD WINAPI Tf1 ( LPVOID n )
{
    HANDLE hEvent = OpenEvent ( EVENT_ALL_ACCESS , false, (LPCWSTR)"MyEvent" );
    if ( !hEvent ) { return -1; }
    // Loop through and wait for an event to occur
    for ( ;; )
    {
        // Wait for the Event
        WaitForSingleObject ( hEvent, INFINITE );
        count++;
        printf("In function1, Counter value: %d\n",count);
        //    No need to Reset the event as its become non signaled as soon as
        //    some thread catches the event.
        if( count > 7 ) return 0;
    }
    CloseHandle(hEvent);
    return 0;
}

DWORD WINAPI Tf2 ( LPVOID n )
{

    HANDLE hEvent = OpenEvent ( EVENT_MODIFY_STATE , false, (LPCWSTR)"MyEvent" );
    if ( !hEvent ) return -1; 

    for ( ;; )
    {
        if( count % 2 == 0) 
            SetEvent (hEvent);
        else
        {
            count++;
            printf("In function2, Counter value: %d\n",count);
        }
        //    No need to Reset the event as its become non signaled as soon as
        //    some thread catches the event.
        if( count > 7 ) return 0;
    }
    CloseHandle(hEvent);
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    //    Create an Auto Reset Event which automatically reset to 
    //    Non Signalled state after being signalled
    HANDLE     hEvent = CreateEvent ( NULL , false , false , (LPCWSTR)"MyEvent" );
    if ( !hEvent ) return -1;
    //    Create a Thread Which will wait for the events to occur
    HANDLE mutex = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, NULL);

    DWORD Id;
    HANDLE hThrd1 = CreateThread ( NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)Tf1,0,0,&Id );
    HANDLE hThrd2 = CreateThread ( NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)Tf2,0,0,&Id );

    if ( !hThrd1 ) { CloseHandle (hEvent); return -1; }
    if ( !hThrd2 ) { CloseHandle (hEvent); return -1; }
    // Wait for a while before continuing....
    Sleep ( 1000 );
    // Give the signal twice as the thread is waiting for 2 signals to occur

    // Wait for the Thread to Die
    WaitForSingleObject ( hThrd1, INFINITE );
    WaitForSingleObject ( hThrd2, INFINITE );

    CloseHandle ( hThrd1 );
    CloseHandle ( hThrd2 );
    CloseHandle ( hEvent );

    system ( "PAUSE" );
    return 0;
}
```

**O/P:**

```
In function1, Counter value: 1
In function1, Counter value: 3
In function2, Counter value: 2
In function2, Counter value: 4
In function2, Counter value: 6
In function1, Counter value: 5
In function1, Counter value: 7
In function2, Counter value: 8
```

**Desired O/P:**

```
In function1, Counter value: 1
In function2, Counter value: 2
In function1, Counter value: 3
In function2, Counter value: 4
In function1, Counter value: 5
In function2, Counter value: 6
In function1, Counter value: 7
In function2, Counter value: 8
```

I know i am not utilizing the power of threads. But my requirement is like this. How can i achieve this?

Comment: Then why use threads? Where does that requirement comes from?

Comment: threads are for parallel behaviour, if you want serial execution use a single thread

Comment: I want to make 2 threads to execute sequentially(not single thread).. control goes from thread1 to thread2 then thread1 then thread2... Btw this is a small assignment given by my professor to me..

Comment: Not again!  This 'please tell me how to totally misuse threads' is now coming up more frequently than 'floating point arithmetic is not accurate'.  Like @EtiennedeMartel says - which miserable textbook/tutorial/page does this rubbish come from?  Oh - professor.  Tell your prof. to come up with better assignments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing to stop race conditions in this code.  You either need two events so the threads play ping-pong with signal and wait, or you protect your counter with a critical section.

**Option 1:**

```
// Thread 1
{
    increment counter
    Signal event 2
    Wait on event 1
}

// Thread 2
{
    Wait on event 2
    increment counter
    Signal event 1
}
```

**Option 2:** (using your existing paradigm)

```
// Thread 1
{
    Wait on event
    Acquire mutex
    if count is even
        increment counter
    end
    Release mutex
}

// Thread 2
{
    Acquire mutex
    if count is even
        Signal event
    else
        increment counter
    end
    Release mutex
}
```

Note that option two is a bit racey in Thread 2...  It might spin multiple times while Thread 1 responds to the event.  In that respect, you may as well remove the event altogether and have both threads spin out...  If you are trying to avoid that, then use my Option 1.

There are other ways to go, including the use of interlocked increments, but try one of the above anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute a thread one after another you can assign each thread an Id and use a shared token, let's say a variable that each thread increments by 1. A thread can grab the token only when it's value is equal to it's Id. Once the token is acquired, the thread executes its body then increments the token by 1 and releases it.


What's the point to use threads if you want sequential execution of code? :)

Comment: I tried this with mutexes but of no use.. Can you please explain me in detail :)

Comment: Here the pseudo: 1-lock_token, 2-compare_it_to_id, 3a-release_if_not_equal_and_exit, 3b-otherwise_execute_thread_body, 4-increment_token, 5-unlock_token